# How to extend RCTEventEmitter while overriding methodQueue getter?

Tags: swift, react-native, react-native-native-module

I'm trying to create a React Native native module in Swift that needs to be run on the main thread and which sends events to JS.  This works fine (as instructed in [RN docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios.html#exporting-swift)):

```swift
@objc(MyModule)
class MyModule: NSObject {
  @objc
  func methodQueue() -> DispatchQueue {
    return DispatchQueue.main
  }
}
```

The [recommended way](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios.html#sending-events-to-javascript) to send events is to extend `RCTEventEmitter`.  When I change `NSObject` to `RCTEventEmitter` in the above code, I get the error:

```
Method 'methodQueue()' with Objective-C selector 'methodQueue' conflicts with getter for 'methodQueue' from superclass 'RCTEventEmitter' with the same Objective-C selector
```

How can I override the `methodQueue` getter while at the same time extending `RCTEventEmitter`? Or is there some other way to send events to JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override it as a var getter:

```swift
  @objc
  override var methodQueue: DispatchQueue {
    get {
      return DispatchQueue.main
    }
  }
```